How to work with pbf files in php/laravel?
I am working on an interface for creating a static map in php/laravel which gets generated by putting together map tiles around a point. Right now I am trying to use azuremaps vector tileset which provides them in a pbf format, as well as some other services who also provide their tiles in a pbf format. Some specify them to be not osm pbf tiles but google protobuf, but I don't think that it makes such a big difference.
Since it's an existing, already pretty large application I can't just use a tile server.
I've used the composer package franksierra/osm-pbf, since it seems to be the only one that exists, but unfortunately I can't get it to work. I know the tiles are valid since I've managed to work with them in a python application.
Here is some code I've tried.
$file_handler = fopen(App::resourcePath('tile.pbf'), 'rb');
        $pbfreader = new Reader($file_handler);
        $file_header = $pbfreader->readFileHeader();
        dd($file_header->getBbox()->getLeft());

With this I get the error:

Error occurred during parsing: Unexpected wire type. In this line:
$file_header = $pbfreader->readFileHeader();

$file_handler = fopen(App::resourcePath('11360.pbf'), 'rb');
        $pbfreader = new Reader($file_handler);
        $file_header = $pbfreader->readFileHeader();
        dd($file_header->getBbox()->getLeft());

Here I get:

Error occurred during parsing: Illegal field number zero.

In the same line.
These are tiles from 2 different providers.
Maybe I am doing something completely wrong since I am still relatively new to php, so please be gentle and detailed in your answers.
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

OSM PBF doesn't contain tiles but raw OSM data. You need a renderer to create tiles from it. Something doesn't add up in your setup.

I see, thank you. Any idea how I could do that on the backend? I could't find anything.
